# Why does this character not reveal SG-1's location in "Secrets"

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, character-motivation

In the closing moments of Stargate SG-1 S02E09 "Secrets", Amaunet looks directly at Daniel but does not give up SG-1's position to Apophis. Given that nowhere else in canon can the host best a goa'uld, without technological help such as the Tollan device, or the symbiote's complicity or duplicity (not even Adria can defend herself against Ba'al), it would appear that at this point it is Amaunet who is in control rather than Sha're.

What would be Amaunet's motivation for keeping the truth from Apophis at this point?

Comment: No... despite Teal'c insisting at first nothing of the host survives, there are several points at which a host influences its goa'uld.  Skar was shown to do it before Sha're did.

Comment: I'm not saying it was Amaunet all along, and I believe she 'slept' to protect the child, but by this point she had reasserted herself. Iirc, skaara coming forward is only after a zat blast, which normally would render the victim unconscious - in this case, it seems klorel took the brunt of it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the host consciousness coming forward (that even happened when Apophis passed out), but the host influencing, or even directly resisting, the parasite personality even while it's dominant. Klorel had several such moments. The relative strength / willpower of both parties is probably relevant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From a dramatic perspective, the purpose of the scene is cast strong doubt on the idea that "nothing of the host survives."  Up to that point in the show, this question (and specifically whether Sha're had survived) was one of the driving questions of the show.  And in the very next episode, "Thor's Hammer," Daniel gets conclusive proof that the host does survive and can even influence the goa'uld's decisions.

Certainly, Amaunet is ultimately the one in charge as this event happens.  However, we know that Sha're is able to influence Amaunet's actions to a certain extent.  She manages to encode a message to her husband while Amaunet is torturing him in "Forever in a Day."  A reasonable inference is that Sha're is trying to help out.

Of course, Sha're's help would be of no use if Amaunet could not be convinced to cooperate.  Her specific personal motivations to do so are unknown, but the goa'uld leaders are all selfish megalomaniacs.  She may not have much personal loyalty to Apophis, and keeping the SGC strong may give her a tool to use against him in the future.  In "The Serpent's Lair," Bra'tac points out that a system lord often had the most to fear from their immediate kin, and Sha're could take momentary advantage of Amaunet's own natural plotting against her husband to cause the goa'uld to make an ill-advised split-second decision.

Comment: "Thor's Hammer" was Season 1. This episode was Season 2.

Answer (score 12):

## Apophis' plan put Amaunet in jeopardy

The creation of the [Harcesis](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Harcesis) child was for Apophis' benefit:

> Apophis has hidden Sha're on Abydos, so that rival Goa'uld will not know of the child, whom he intends to someday be his new host.
>
> — Stargate Wiki: ["Secrets"](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Secrets_(episode))

The pregnancy made Amaunet vulnerable to Apophis' enemies:

> Back on Abydos, Daniel Jackson and Teal'c attempt to leave for Earth with Sha're, but are stopped when a Goa'uld pyramid ship lands on top of the pyramid. Amaunet comes forth, saying Apophis has come for her. It turns out to be the ship of Heru'ur, a sworn enemy of Apophis, who has come with the intent of stealing Sha're's child.
>
> — Stargate Wiki: ["Secrets"](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Secrets_(episode))

Goa'uld tend strongly toward self-interest and vindictiveness.  Having suffered through pregnancy for Apophis and nearly losing her life, Amaunet likely decided to retain SG-1 as potential allies against Apophis.

Comment: Is Wikia considered canonical?

Comment: @RonJohn - Going by my memory, the Stargate Wiki describes the episode accurately and more eloquently than I currently can.  Credit where credit is due.

Comment: The Wikia itself isn't canonical, but when the information is accurate, it's an effective tool for conveying canonical information.

Answer (score 1):

They covered it later in the following season.  Because she was pregnant Sha're was stronger than the goa'uld. As the pregnancy progressed the power shifted more to the host, even up to the point the host has full control. During the time of full control she even started that the goa'uld was *upset* with Apophis and was actually going along with the plan to hide the child once it was born.

So partially, the goa'uld was more easily swayed to say nothing because her power was weakened. Because she was angry at Apophis, she wanted her child kept away from him and probably figured at the time that SG-1 was the best way for that to happen (as we hadn't encountered ancients at this point if the arc).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Whilst this may answer the question it would be better if you could include the sources directly into your answer!

Comment: If i want in bed at 350am i probably would.  I'll try to remember to edit the answer tomorrow, and thanks for the welcome.